# Recovering from an abruptly ended make

Tags: makefile, resume

When I compile large programs (like gcc or clang for example) there is a chance that my computer will overheat, and be forced to shut down.

I would like to resume the `make` process from where I left off. The problem seems to be that there are half completed/written `.o` files that are floating around that cause the rest of the built to break (this is especially bad when I specify `-j 8`)

Is there an easy way to get around this problem (whithout doing a `make clean` or `make distclean` or the like)?

Using GNU Make 3.81

Comment: Maybe not an *easy* way, but... You could have marker files that indicate that a given object file is complete. Something like `foo_done: foo.cc <CR> gcc $< -o foo.o <CR> touch $@`

Comment: @Beta I did not write the makefiles. How could I implement this for generic makefiles

Comment: You mean without modifying any makefiles? I don't think you can. Just do a `make clean`. If your computer's average time between failures is shorter than your build time, you have bigger problems.

Comment: @beta I am willing modify them, but it has to be a change I can make programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines as Beta's comment, but more reliable and less confusing IMO, would be to change your compile rule so that you compile to a temporary file, then at the end rename it to the real file.  So where you might have something like:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

instead you would use something like:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@.tmp -c $< \
            && mv -f $@.tmp $@
```

You may or may not want to add a "rm -f $@" as well.

As to whether you can make this change "programmatically" or not, it all dependes on your makefile and how it's structured.  If it's a well-formed makefile then you can just make these changes in a few places in a few implicit rules, as above.